# Where to modify the contact 7 select options in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 and here is the actual contact form 7 code to display the select drop down

```
<div class="select-wpr">[select* program id:program first_as_label required "Choose your program of interest"]</div></div>
<div class="full-width">
<div class="select-wpr">[select* campus id:campus first_as_label "Choose campus"]</div>
</div>
```

Where can I go and modify the actual select drop down options? I want to add `<optgroup>` to the select options but can't find where to go and modify that. Where is that located in wordpress?

Comment: You might find this thread helpful:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/select-menu-dropdown-bug-optgroup-and-multiple-selections/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my best knowledge there is no possibility to use optgroups with contact form 7. You may send a feature request to the developers, but i doubt that they will implement it as it is not needed too often.

The first possible solution is to use a more flexible Plugin than Contact Form 7 for this purpose or you code this particular form yourself.

The second possibilitiy is to use a JavaScript approach which modifies the select after it is loaded:

```js
$(function(){
  var foundin = $('#some_select option:contains("optgroup-")');
  $.each(foundin, function(value){
    var updated = $(this).val().replace('optgroup-','');
    $(this).nextUntil('option:contains("endoptgroup")').wrapAll('<optgroup label="'+updated+'"></optgroup>');
  });
  $('#some_select option:contains("optgroup-")').remove();
  $('#some_select option:contains("endoptgroup")').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="some_select">
  <option>optgroup-First Group</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>endoptgroup</option>
  <option>optgroup-Second Group</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>Some Option</option>
  <option>endoptgroup</option>
</select>
```

(found on CodePen: https://codepen.io/adrian-ortega/pen/Ivzjh)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `optgroup` elements in Contact Form 7 drop downs as it doesn't seem to support it in the shortcode syntax unfortunately. The [documentation](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/) on the official site outlines the possible options.

```
id:(id)
class:(class)
default:(num)
default:1_2_3
multiple
include_blank
first_as_label
data:(name)
```